# restrict uibDatepicker pop up to accept only digits and '-'

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a requirement that I need to let user only enter digits and `-` into date picker and prevent user from entering other characters, how can I achieve this?

for example I want prevent user from entering text like `asasdfas` in input field for datepicker.

I used this code in `parseDate` function inside uibDatepicker code but view doesn't get updated.

```
 var regex = /[^0-9\-]/g;
 viewValue = viewValue.replace(regex, '');
```

here is a plunk to play around: http://plnkr.co/edit/AKFhTG162Ck5Blt0ZBH7?p=preview

Comment: That is a blank plunk ..

Comment: @Alok thanks, fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the input type to date restricts the user from inputting any extra text.

```
<input type="date" />
```

The problem is that enables the HTML5 default date picker. I have added a little css to hide that part but you would need to check it other browsers. I was unable to remove the arrows and again I will leave you to do it.

Hope it helps. I forked your [PLUNK HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/koII102xM2GF7ORFvMwu?p=preview)